# How does airfoil affect the coefficient of lift vs. AOA slope?

Tags: aerodynamics, aircraft-physics, airfoil

I'm trying to understand whether the airfoil shape can affect the slope of Cl vs. AOA (coefficient of lift vs. angle of attack) in the "linear" portion, e.g., from a few degrees negative to about 10 degrees. As an example, I picked 9 different airfoils from the NACA 4 and 6 series on airfoiltool.com and they all have pretty much the same slope in their linear regions (Rn 1'000'000):
[image: Cl vs AOA for 9 NACA airfoils]

The question I have is, if I would like a steeper slope (more effect on lift with less change in AOA) are there specific airfoils I should look at? Or any specific airfoil characteristics? Or is this slope basically given by physics for "reasonable overall well-performing" airfoils?

Answer (score 1):

The airfoil affects the lift curve slope only very little; theoretically the slope should be [a bit steeper](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/31268/what-is-the-effect-of-airfoil-thickness-on-aerodynamic-lift/31278#31278) for thicker airfoils.

But that pales in comparison to the effects of wing planform. Here the biggest influence is from the wing's [aspect ratio and sweep](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14508/what-is-the-method-to-calculate-a-finite-wings-lift-from-its-sectional-airfoil/14559?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C110.3537#14559). Another factor is the flight Mach number and the Reynolds number.

But there is one trick to artificially increase the lift curve slope for a given planform and flight speed: Add a [camber flap](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/5018/why-and-when-to-use-flaps/9445#9445) and move it in sync with angle of attack. This will shift the zero-lift angle inversely to the change in angle of attack. A purely mechanical solution would use a [flap with a large control horn](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/82901/what-is-the-benefit-of-a-horn-aileron/82925#82925), so that $c_{r\alpha}$ becomes positive while $c_{r\eta}$ stays negative. However, this is prone to flutter at higher speeds, so depending on the planned speed range a hydraulic or electric actuator, driven by a control unit which is hooked up to an AoA sensor, might be the better solution.

Comment: Do you have a link or short explanation for why the lift curve slope is not (cannot be?) affected by airfoil shape? Thanks for the flap links!

Comment: @TvE Potential flow theory. And lots of windtunnel data. Follow the links in the answer or ask more specifically. As it stands, this question is on a level of "why can I not change gravity". You can't.